# WARNING: LoopBack connector "mongodb" is not installed

Tags: node.js, loopback

I m following a tutorial to create a react chat application with Loopback3 API but I m getting following Error when i try to run my application server ,I retried to install  npm install loopback-connector-mongodb --save but still getting same issue. Do i need to  install mongodb again? :-

```
WARNING: LoopBack connector "mongodb" is not installed as any of the following modules:
    
     ./connectors/mongodb
    loopback-connector-mongodb
    
    To fix, run:
    
        npm install loopback-connector-mongodb --save
    
    C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:280
        throw err;
        ^
    
    Error: Cannot create data source "db":
    WARNING: LoopBack connector "mongodb" is not installed as any of the following modules:
    
     ./connectors/mongodb
    loopback-connector-mongodb
    
    To fix, run:
    
        npm install loopback-connector-mongodb --save
    
        at DataSource.setup (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:457:26)
        at new DataSource (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:138:8)
        at Registry.createDataSource (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback\lib\registry.js:364:14)
        at dataSourcesFromConfig (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:570:19)
        at Function.app.dataSource (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:269:16)
        at C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:191:9
        at C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:282:5
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at forEachKeyedObject (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:281:20)
        at setupDataSources (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:181:3)
        at execute (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:39:3)
        at bootLoopBackApp (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-boot\index.js:154:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\server\server.js:28:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    Emitted 'error' event on DataSource instance at:
        at DataSource.setup (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:457:12)
        at new DataSource (C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\ReactJS\chatServer\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:138:8)
        [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

But Here is my package.json:-

```
{
  "name": "chatServer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node .",
    "posttest": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "helmet": "^3.10.0",
    "loopback": "^3.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^6.2.0",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^6.0.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strong-error-handler": "^4.0.0",
    "ws": "^7.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
    "eslint-config-loopback": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "description": "chatServer"
}
```

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Should `mongodb` be added as a dependency? It is not present in that package.json

Comment: @Manny thank you for your attention but it still giving me same issue

Comment: would you kindly link the tutorial so that there is additional context? That will provide guidance on where there may be an error.